# bash: How to extract episode number from a string

Tags: bash

Suppose you have this string variable in bash:

```
filename="House Of Lies 5x02 HDTV XviD [DivxTotaL]"
```

What can I do to get the `5x02` part?

I've tried with grep with no luck:

```
echo "$filename" > grep -c '[0-9]x[0-9]{2}'
```

Comment: You'll want to use sed or awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `-c` which you are passing with grep is wrong

`-c` Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output.

```
$ echo $filename | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,2}x[0-9]{1,3}'
5x02
```

`-o` Prints only the matching part of the lines.

`-E` Extended Regex

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "$filename" | egrep -o '[0-9]x[0-9]{2}'
```

`>file` redirects output to a file; `|cmd` pipes it to another command. `-c` counts the number of matches, which isn't useful here; `-o` outputs the matching string(s). To be able to use `{2}` you need to enable extended regexes, which `egrep` does.